# Changing p-value when using elrm in r

Tags: r

I am a new user to R and would like to perform an exact logistic regression. I have chosen this method because my dependent variable is binary (i.e. 0 for failure and 1 for success), and have continuous independent variables. I also have a very small sample size of n=10. The following is a sample of the code I have written.

```
library(elrm)
BaselineSteps = c(4202, 7244, 4374.6, 2965.6, 4263.5, 1814.1, 3243.1, 3102.9, 4652.5, 6324.9)
StepsClass = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
Const = rep(1,length(StepsClass))

dat = data.frame(pred = BaselineSteps, trials = Const, success = StepsClass)
m.stepsFromSteps = elrm(formula = success/trials ~ pred, interest = ~pred, iter = 22000, dataset = dat, burnIn = 2000)
```

I am trying to use the baseline average steps/day taken by a subject to determine which class of recovery pattern they will fall into (0 or 1). However, when I run only the last line itself where elrm is implemented (changing nothing), I obtain drastically different p-values every time that I run it. See following:

```
> m.stepsFromSteps = elrm(formula = success/trials ~pred, interest = ~pred, iter=30000, dataset = dat, burnIn=5000)
> m.stepsFromSteps$p.values
pred 
0.16176

> m.stepsFromSteps = elrm(formula = success/trials ~pred, interest = ~pred, iter=30000, dataset = dat, burnIn=5000)
> m.stepsFromSteps$p.values
pred 
0.613

> m.stepsFromSteps = elrm(formula = success/trials ~pred, interest = ~pred, iter=30000, dataset = dat, burnIn=5000)
> m.stepsFromSteps$p.values
pred 
1

> m.stepsFromSteps = elrm(formula = success/trials ~pred, interest = ~pred, iter=30000, dataset = dat, burnIn=5000)
> m.stepsFromSteps$p.values
pred 
0.83056
```

I have tried dramatically increasing iterations (iter = 50000) as well as burnIn, but to no avail. The p-values still drastically change each time I run this. I have actually performed 50 exact logistic regressions in this same format using different predictors and/or classes, and all of them have the same issue of producing different p-values each time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe that what is happening is that you have too few observations for your Markov chain to converge on a stable solution. The `elrm` function internally calls the MCMC function directly from C, where I assume it generates a random seed. The Monte Carlo sampling there would be highly sensitive to the initialization step (based on the seed) with so few observations. I advise that you acquire more data but I'm not entirely sure on this one. Might be a question for cross validated.

Comment: This is what I assumed to be happening as well, but was hoping it wasn't the case. I agree, the small sample size makes it difficult to converge. Thank you for your input!